# jquery .animate() height to auto

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jquery.. I'm having to animate a div to a certain height.. And again on the next click, i need to animate it to height auto. I am able to animate only when i provide the height in px.. here is my code.. can any1 suggest how to find the height of the div on page load.

```
 $("#photobutton").click(function(){
                          var $text = $("#photobutton").text();

                         if($text == "hide photos") 
                         {
                            $("#photocontainer").animate({height: '144px'}, 1000);
                            $("#photobutton").text("more photos");
                         }
                         else if($text == "more photos")
                         {
                            $("#photocontainer").animate({height: '100%'}, 1000);

                            $("#photobutton").text("hide photos");
                         }

                      });
```

on the if condition i want the div to collapse to height144px.. and in the else conditions i want the div to stretch to its full height to display all the elements..

Comment: What do you need the 100% height of? The entire page?

Comment: Can you put it in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second `animate()` call, assuming you want this div to fill the height of its parent, use:

```
$("#photocontainer").animate({height: $("#photocontainer").parent().height()+'px'}, 1000);
```

**EDIT**

1. Example of animating height to fill parent's height: http://jsfiddle.net/techfoobar/HXjfe/
2. Example of animating height to fill window's height: http://jsfiddle.net/techfoobar/C37rs/1/

**EDIT #2**

Animating to auto height: http://jsfiddle.net/techfoobar/psexn/3/

jQuery's animate function will not animate to auto height by itself. In fact, it will not animate to any height that cannot be determined prior to the animation.

We can however get it to do it. But it involves a rather ugly hack. The hack is to hide the div, set height to auto, note the height, revert the height and visibility. Once we have the target height, animate it.

Comment: I cannot fix the height for the parent either

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to work with pixels, not percents.

```
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
```

Retrive the relevant one, and use `.height();` to set it.

Comment: i need to find the height of the div..  $("#div").height() doesn't seem to deliver that..

Comment: Set it to a pixel value of the height you need. You mention the div is within another div, so as long as the height of that div is fixed (i.e. it doesn't collapse once the photos are hidden) you should be fine. I think your problem is that you hide the photo div, and the parent div height becomes 0.

Comment: No buddy.. on the if condition i want the div to collapse to height144px.. and in the else conditions i want the div to stretch to its full height.. cannot use the parent div

Comment: "strect to its full height". What is the div's full height? Is it an absolute value, or relative to a parent container?

Comment: relative to the contents added in dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Jquery's `animate` method works just fine with percentages as well as pixels.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/KH8Gf/11/

This leads me to believe the issue is that you haven't properly defined a parent for the div `photocontainer`. When you state a height in percentage, it means, x% of the parent. If a parent is not defined, it won't work with percentages.

Post your HTML markup and CSS if possible.

**UPDATE**

When you're animating the exapndsion of photocontainer, you have to specify to what height it should expand. To do this, you need to know the height you want, either in percentage or pixels.

If you want `photocontainer` to be able to hold a variable amount of data, you need to change your strategy. Define `photocontainer` to have height `auto`, and then when expand is clicked, add the new elements inside `photocontainer`. `Photocontainer` will automatically expand to an appropriate size.

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/KH8Gf/21/

Comment: the contents in the photocontainer are dynamic from database.. and so i cannot fix the height of the parent as well.. Is it possible to get the height of the div in pixels.??

Comment: hey buddy! $("#photocontainer").animate({height: 'auto'}, 1000); is this what you mean?

Comment: i succeeded in it with .css(height, auto) method.. i want it to be animated to the auto height.. animate({height: '100%'}, 1000);  ---> this did not work